# NodeJs Streams, pipelines, and https posts

Tags: node.js, https, stream, node-streams

I needing a bit of a sanity check.

I am running Node 11.10.1

I have a process that reads from a oracle db using the nodejs oracledb library. There is a streaming function which I do a select * and stream the results in batches of 10k objects. I then  post this data to an indexer via https. The object stream is injected into a pipeline function.

I have been using he following code for awhile. Im trying to debug throughput. Sometimes I can see about 2k documents a second being processed through this pipeline. Most times I see <150. Before I jump to debugging my index server. I want to make sure these functions are coded properly.

```
  async function streamReindex(databaseStream) {
    let pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline)
    await pipeline(
      selectStream,//  "oracledb": "^4.0.0", stream function
      camelize.camelizeStream(), //"camelize2": "^1.0.0", library wrapped in ,"through2": "^3.0.1" library to make it an object stream
      JSONStream.stringify(), //"JSONStream": "^1.3.5"
      reindexClient.streamReindex(core)
    )
  }

// reindexClient code.

  function streamReindex(core) {
    const updateUrl = baseUrl + core + '/update'
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      'auth': `${user.username}:${user.password}`,
    }
    let postStream = https.request(updateUrl, options, (res) => {
      let response = {
        status: {
          code: res.statusCode,
          message: res.statusMessage
        },
        headers: res.headers,
      }
      if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        postStream.destroy(new Error(JSON.stringify(response)))
      }
    })
    postStream.on('error', (err)=>{
      throw new Error(err)
    })
    postStream.on('socket', (socket) => {
      socket.setKeepAlive(true, 240000)
    })
    return postStream
  }


  async function selectStream(sql, bindings = [], fetchSize = 
     fetchArraySize) {
     let connection = await knex.client.acquireConnection()

    log.info(`Fetch size is set to ${fetchSize}`)
    let select = connection.queryStream(sql, bindings, {
      fetchArraySize: fetchSize,
      outFormat: outFormat
    })

    select.on('error', (err) => {
      log.error('Oracle Error Event', err)
      knex.client.releaseConnection(connection)
    })

    select.on('close', () => {
      log.info('Oracle Close Event')
      knex.client.releaseConnection(connection)
      select = null
      connection = null
    })

    return select
  }
```

If I remove the reindexClient.streamReindex(core) function from the pipeline. I see throughput of ~5k objects a second. I was looking into the highwatermark functionality of streams but cant seem to figure out how to apply it on the postStream. If I console.log post stream it also doesn't say its in object mode. Which means  its highwatermark is in bytes which has a low threshold I believe.

If you need anymore info I will try to provide as much as possible.

Comment: This is a side note on the layer (oracledb) that doesn't seem to be the issue: don't forget to tune `fetchArraySize`.

Comment: Hey Christopher. I recognize your name from the node oracledb github!. Amazing support! I ive used a variable fetch array size. Right now iv settled  on 10k due to memory constraints.

Comment: Sounds like reindexClient.streamReindex(core) is the issue (based on what you said). Do you know how it works? If the issue is network latency, then there's not a lot you can do with code. However, if it's processing the data as it's coming in, then it could be creating back pressure that slows everything down. Maybe try commenting out the processing part to see how fast the data flows in without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I increased my throughput by almost 500/docs a second by implementing the JSONStream.stringify() function myself. Since it didn't allow me to set the watermark. Once i did I was able to really ramp it up but I could use all my memory. Setting with the following code got me to a stable memory footprint a long with better throughput. I also got rid of the through2 library and put the camelize functionality within my stringify Transfrom. Most of the code and explanation can be found here: https://blog.dmcquay.com/2017/09/06/node-stream-db-results-with-transform.html

Here is the code:

```
  function camelizeAndStringify() {
    let first = true
    const serialize = new Transform({
      objectMode: true,
      highWaterMark: 1000,
      transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        if (first) {
          this.push('[' + JSON.stringify(camelize(chunk)))
          first = false
        } else {
          this.push(',' + JSON.stringify(camelize(chunk)))
        }
        callback()
        chunk = null
      },
      flush(callback) {
        this.push(']')
        callback()
      }
    })
    return serialize
  }
```

Comment: My saga continues now with this memory leak issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259942/nodejs-streams-help-find-my-memory-leak

Answer (score 1):

Although your problem doesn't seem to be with oracledb, I'm putting this here so I can format the code.  You might get some performance benefit from tuning the oracledb stream, for example like:

```
   diff --git a/lib/queryStream.js b/lib/queryStream.js
   index 08ddc720..11953e4b 100644
   --- a/lib/queryStream.js
   +++ b/lib/queryStream.js
   @@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ const { Readable } = require('stream');
    class QueryStream extends Readable {

      constructor(rs) {
   -    super({ objectMode: true });
   +    super({ objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 64 });  // choose your own value
    this._fetching = false;
    this._numRows = 0;
```

A PR to allow the high watermark to be set as a `queryStream()` option would be welcome.

Comment: Two notes: Later, brief testing didn't show this patch to add much improvement, but the original (also brief) testing did.  YMMV.  Also, review the updated [`selectstream.js`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/selectstream.js) example. We recently updated it to use destroy() since this can reduce peak memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this more! I added my selectStream function to the question for your reference. I have been  having  a memory leak issue and seeing how the example does the destroy is very interesting! I wonder if implementing that  would fix my leak. I also see  that it says dont close connection on 'end'. Which is what im doing. :S . Ultimately I have seen a performance increase by buffing up my index service's hardware that the http is making a call to. But I would still like to make sure all my code above is proper!