# Nodejs Streams - Help find my memory leak

Tags: node.js, stream, node-oracledb

So I have a process that selects from a table. I partition my select programmatically into 20 sub-selects. I then go through each on of those select and stream its data to an indexing client (solr). Every select memory jumps up and holds until I get an OOM.

I logged when each query went off and can be seen in in the following charts:
[image: Each column indicates an instance of a new query starting]

These correlate with each jump in the this memory graph:

[image: Each jump is a new query]

14 of 20 queries ran before I oomed.

I see this behavior with code that is similar but with a delta that runs every 15 mins. Every delta holds some sort of memory until it eventually causes the server to crash with OOM (which recovers)

I have tried to track down issues with the delta past but gave up and just created a way to gracefully restart. What am I missing here?

Here is my entire code chain that makes this work... I know its a lot to look through but I figured as much detail as possible would help.

Library Stack:

```
"node": "~11.10.1"
"knex": "^0.20.9",
"oracledb": "^4.0.0"
"camelize2": "^1.0.0"
```

Knex - DB connection factory

```
'use strict'

const objection = require('objection')
const knex = require('knex')


module.exports = function ObjectionFactory(log) {
  class MyObjection extends objection.Model {
    constructor() {
      super()
    }
    static get tableName() {
      return ''
    }
  }

  MyObjection.pickJsonSchemaProperties = true

  log.info('Connecting to Oracle Pluggable...', {
    host: 'myHost',
    username: 'myUser',
    database: 'myDatabase"
  })

  const knexInstance = knex({
    client: 'oracledb',
    connection: 'connectionInfo',
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10
    },
    acquireConnectionTimeout: 10000
  })

  process.once('SIGINT', () => {
    log.info('Disconnecting from Oracle Pluggable.')
    knexInstance.destroy()
      .then(() => process.exit(0))
      .catch(() => process.exit(1))
  })
  // Shut down cleanly for nodemon
  process.once('SIGUSR2', () => {
    log.info('Disconnecting from Oracle Pluggable')
    knexInstance.destroy()
      .then(() => process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2'))
      .catch(() => process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2'))
  })

  const knexBoundClass = MyObjection.bindKnex(knexInstance)
  knexBoundClass.tag = 'Oracle Connection'
  return knexBoundClass
}
```

My Select Stream Code:

```
module.exports = function oracleStream(log, MyObjection) {

  const knex = MyObjection.knex()
  const fetchArraySize = 10000
  const outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT

  return {
    selectStream
  }

  async function selectStream(sql, bindings = [], fetchSize = fetchArraySize) {
    let connection = await knex.client.acquireConnection()

    log.info(`Fetch size is set to ${fetchSize}`)
    let select = connection.queryStream(sql, bindings, {
      fetchArraySize: fetchSize,
      outFormat: outFormat
    })

    select.on('error', (err) => {
      log.error('Oracle Error Event', err)
      knex.client.releaseConnection(connection)
    })

    select.on('end', () => {
      log.info('Destroying the Stream')
      select.destroy()
    })

    select.on('close', () => {
      log.info('Oracle Close Event')
      knex.client.releaseConnection(connection)
      select = null
      connection = null
    })

    return select
  }

}
```

My index/stream pipeline code

```
async function indexJob() {
    const reindexStartTime = new moment().local()

    let rowCount = 0
    log.info('Reindex Started at', reindexStartTime.format())
    let queryNumber = 1
    const partitionedQueries = ['Select * from table where 1=1', 'Select * from table where 2=2', 'Select * from table where 3=3'] //There  would be  20 queries in this array
    let partitionedQueriesLength = partitionedQueries.length

    while (partitionedQueries.length > 0) {
      let query = partitionedQueries.pop()

      log.info('RUNNING Query', {
        queryNumber: `${queryNumber++} of ${partitionedQueriesLength}`,
        query: query
      })

      let databaseStream = await oracleStream.selectStream(query, [], 10000) //10k represents the oracle fetch size

      databaseStream.on('data', () => {
        rowCount++
      })

      let logEveryFiveSec = setInterval(() => {
        log.info('Status: ', getReindexInfo(reindexStartTime, rowCount))
      }, 5000)

      try {
        let pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline)
        await pipeline(
          databaseStream,
          camelizeAndStringify(),
          streamReindex(core)
        )
      } catch (err) {
        databaseStream.destroy(err)
        throw new JobFailedError(err)
      } finally {
        databaseStream.destroy()
        clearInterval(logEveryFiveSec)
      }
    }
  }

  function camelizeAndStringify() {
    let first = true
    const serialize = new Transform({
      objectMode: true,
      highWaterMark: 1000,
      transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        if (first) {
          this.push('[' + JSON.stringify(camelize(chunk)))
          first = false
        } else {
          this.push(',' + JSON.stringify(camelize(chunk)))
        }
        callback()
        chunk = null
      },
      flush(callback) {
        this.push(']')
        callback()
      }
    })
    return serialize
  }


function streamReindex(core) {
    const updateUrl = baseUrl + core + '/update'
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      'auth': `${user.username}:${user.password}`,
    }
    let postStream = https.request(updateUrl, options, (res) => {
      let response = {
        status: {
          code: res.statusCode,
          message: res.statusMessage
        },
        headers: res.headers,
      }
      if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        postStream.destroy(new Error(JSON.stringify(response)))
      }
    })
    postStream.on('error', (err)=>{
      throw new Error(err)
    })
    postStream.on('socket', (socket) => {
      socket.setKeepAlive(true, 110000)
    })
    return postStream
  }
```

***EDIT 1:***
I tried removing knex out of the equation by doing a singular connection to my db with  the oracle library. Unfortunately I still see the same behavior.
This is how I changed my select to *not* use knex

```
  async function selectStream(sql, bindings = [], fetchSize = fetchArraySize) {

    const connectionInfo = {
      user: info.user,
      password: info.password,
      connectString: info.host +'/'+info.database
    }

    const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(connectionInfo)

    log.info('Connection was successful!')

    log.info(`Fetch size is set to ${fetchSize}`)
    let select = connection.queryStream(sql, bindings, {
      fetchArraySize: fetchSize,
      outFormat: outFormat
    })

    select.on('error', async (err) => {
      log.error('Oracle Error Event', err)
      await connection.close()
    })

    select.on('end', () => {
      log.info('Destroying the Stream')
      select.destroy()
    })

    select.on('close', async () => {
      log.info('Oracle Close Event')
      await connection.close()
    })

    return select
  }
```

Comment: Review the latest node-oracledb [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) and [draft documentation](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#streamingresults), since we recently updated the recommendations.  You do seem to be using it OK, but it never hurts to check.  Also, can you reproduce it outside of Knex?  And it never hurts to update to the latest Node.js and node-oracledb, since there are known mem leaks in the Node.js N-API layer.

Comment: I havnt tried to remove knex out of the picture due to knex being used much more elseware in the app. The node version is determined by what our opa guys say we can use so unfortunately I can't update that. I will try to up oracledb to the latest.

Comment: If you still have problems, we could look at the node-oracledb level as long as you aren't using Knex - you'd need to simplify the testcase to make it manageable to debug.  Also, Node 11 is long dead and likely an overall liability.  You can try with a newer version just to compare.

Comment: I'll see what I can whip up tomorrow. I'll try to remove knex from the equition. Also see if I can jump to the latest LTS of node. I appreciate your support of oracledb. Always nice to see your name pop up.

Comment: I just got the code running without knex. just doing a singular-non pooling method. Ill report back on how it  works out.

Comment: I get the same  behavior removing knex. Ill add an  edit to my question showing  the code I tried.

Comment: I upped my  version or oracledb to 4.2.0. Same issue.

Comment: Im trying with node 12 now locally. Being remote really slows down my database access. Ill report back with any more results.

Comment: end of weekend update. I cant reproduce the memory leak locally. I only see it while its running in my cloud foundry instance. interesting...

Comment: So the Node.js versions are different between your local machine and cloud foundry? Perhaps that's where the issue is...

Comment: Actually I reverted everything back to original dependencies and confirmed that all versions are the same in cloud foundry and local. This https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2410682_1.html seems suspect now

Comment: That bug was fixed long ago.  What versions of Oracle client and Oracle DB do you have?

Comment: While im not sure about he version or oracle db we are running off the top of my head, I do know that we DO NOT have that patch - according to the DBAs. We are running *i think* instant client in the 12 range